# How to change action bar background when using the Support Library?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I tried example code (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) on 'Customize the Background'.

but I want to know how this works. -> '@drawable/actionbar_background'

It seems to add 'actionbar_background.png' file to somewhere res folder but I don't know where.

So I changed source like this.

```
<!-- Action Bar styles -->
<style
    name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

    <item name="android:background">#FF6600</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">#FF6600</item>
</style>
```

but this part

```
<item name="background">#FF6600</item>
```

doesn't work.
I don't know what type is appropriate.

Comment: did you have values-11 and values-14? you need put your style in that folder too

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I have those folders. but it can't explain why background color code doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use this in style.xml in **res>>Values**

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#4cb9f6</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @Cloud : Yeah I am using it with support library appcompat_v7
But this effect changes your whole applications theme :)

Comment: Oh, below this '<!-- Support library compatibility -->'; line was unnecessary codes.. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Hello @ShankarRegmi, when using `parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">` as parent theme, `<item name="android:background">#4cb9f6</item>` shows error on the hex_color as **cannot resolve symbol "#4cb9f6"**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also couldn't change the background using the XML style file, so I just changed the color inside the "onCreate" of my activity.

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(MY_COLOR)));
```

Maybe this isn't the best practice, but it is functional.